# Pause video(s) when lightbox is closed - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

We have multiple `videos` on our web page, most videos appear in a `light box`, when we're watching a `video` and decide to close it we've wired up a `javascript` event which will be triggered when the user closes the light box, what we're trying to achieve is when the user clicks close we want to loop all `videos` that are on the page and pause the given one that is currently playing, reason being is because even though the `light box` is closed the video continues to play.

This is what I have so far:

```
  window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className.indexOf("close") != -1) {

      var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

      for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
          video[i].addEventListener('timeupdate', function(event) {
              var vid = event.target
              console.log("here")
              vid.pause();
          })
      }

      console.log("close video background");
  }

});
```

Now the problem with this script is when we click close for the first time it wires an `Event Listener` to the given videos and then pauses them.  The issue is if I reopen the video and click play it'll pause straight away due to the `Event Listener` can someone shed any light into how I can go about pausing a video correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

  for(var i = 0; i < video.length; i++){
   (function(vid) {
      vid.currentTime = 0;
      vid.pause();
  })(video[i]);
  }
```